# Send DateTime from ASP.NET to angularjs as struct, not a string

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, datetime

I'm facing an issue, where I send a complex object from ASP.NET backend to AngularJS frontend. This object consists of DateTime property and a list of objects which also contain DateTime property. All of these properties are sent to frontend as strings and I need to process (convert to Date object) them manually. The problem is that multiple different objects are sent from backend in this way, so one never knows which property is DateTime and which is not, which neccessarily leads to running through 'graph' (= all properties and "subproperties" of objects), checking if the current property is DateTime-like and converting string to Date.

All this breadth-first graph processing takes lots of the processor time which should be used rather for processing the DateTimes and for the huge amount of data which is sent it takes e.g. 10 seconds. So I'd need to know if there is any automatic way either to send the DateTime structs to frontend as structs, not strings, or to process them somehow automatically.

Thanks for any advice in advance.

Comment: The answer probably depends on the encoding used to transfer the data! I would presume though that you're using JSON which only has a few limited types that can be used - array, object, string, number & boolean (think that's all of them!)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the protocol you are using for sending data from your BE to the FE. If you are working with JSON like most of us, then you are limited to [these](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp) field value types, *date* type is not supported, so answer on your question would be **NO**, your data will be returned to the FE as a properly formatted string, timestamp number or a object structure, which represents date fields as json.

If you stick to JSON, you could look into optimization of own date conversation mechanism. For example, if you use regexps, maybe it is worth to replace them on something which is not as clean, but works faster.